# How to add security header parameters to SOAP Request

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soap-client

I have to add security header to Soap request as below,

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2349028390dnjnsja
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">sdfasfdweww</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2016-02-02T10:21:26.247Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I am doing it below way, but getting 404 - Address Not Found Error and header is not getting added to SOAP request.

```
        BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider) ars1;
        provider.getRequestContext().put(Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS, getEndPointURL(proxyType)) ;

        AuthorizationPolicy authzPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy();
        authzPolicy.setUserName("username");
        authzPolicy.setPassword("password");
        provider.getRequestContext().put(AuthorizationPolicy.class.getName(), authzPolicy);
```

What is going wrong in it ?